# WordPress site not connecting to DB on non-www

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm having an issue with my WordPress site where it's unable to connect to the database on the non-www domain. I'm trying to rewrite all non-www requests as www with the following rule, but it's had no effect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

On my server, I currently have two `.htaccess` files–one in the root directory, which redirects the naked domain into a sub-directory that contains my website (see below), and another in this sub-directory, which rewrites some default WordPress URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-directory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-directory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub-directory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For DNS, I have an A record that points `@` to my server's IP address, and a CNAME that points `www` to `@`.

My `wp-config.php` file includes the following condition for reading database credentials:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] !== 'www.domain.com') {
  include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-config-local.php');
  define('WP_LOCAL', true);
}else {
  // Production credentials
}
```

I understand that domain.com fails to connect to my database because its `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` becomes `domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com`, but instead of adding both in the credentials condition, I thought the `.htaccess` rewrite would get around this. I'm struggling to determine where exactly the issue is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the non-www rule was executed after the sub-directory redirect. Once placed before, everything worked as expected.